# Emacs org does not evaluate source blocks at export anymore (version 8.3.2)

Tags: emacs

I have org-mode on two computers. On one, the version is 8.2.5h; one the other, 8.3.2.

Evaluation of source blocks works on the machine with the 8.2.5h version but not on the 8.3.2 version.

Here is a minimal example:

```
* Emacs org / R / latex. 

  Make a random number. 

  #+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R*
    x <- rbeta(1000,10,10)
  #+END_SRC



  Plot the whole thing. 

  #+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R* :exports none
    pdf(file="fig1.pdf", width=8, height=6)
    hist(x, main="")
    dev.off()
  #+END_SRC


  Now put it in this text file. 

  #+BEGIN_SRC latex
    \begin{figure}[h!]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}    
      \caption{Gamma distribution}
      \label{fig:hist-gamma}
    \end{figure}
  #+END_SRC


  Now a latex equation:

  #+BEGIN_SRC latex
    \begin{equation}
      \label{eq:eq1}
      y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{it} + \varepsilon_{it}
    \end{equation}
  #+END_SRC
```

When I export this to latex with org mode version 8.2.5h, I get a pdf with the figure, the latex equation etc. When I export the same file to latex with org mode version 8.3.2, the source blocks are not evaluated; only the code for the first source block is shown.

I played with changing switches, none of these works. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the variable org-export-babel-evaluate. For some reason that was set to nil. Apparently not an org-version problem but the description states "This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in version 24.1 of Emacs", so maybe that was the issue.